# JMSReplyTo - How to create a generic camel route for VM/Artemis/IBM MQ

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis, spring-camel

I have the following service.

- Spring boot 2.5.13
- Camel 3.18.0
- JMS

I want to use an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis, standalone ActiveMQ Artemis, and IBM MQ.

I've managed to get all 3 running and connecting, but one thing I cant figure out is the JMSReplyTo option.

**Running locally with embedded broker:**

This runs fine. I can write a message to the queue and a response is send to the JMSReplyTo:

```java
public void sendRequest(){
    ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue = new ActiveMQQueue("RESPONSE_QUEUE");
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("REQUEST_QUEUE", "Hello", pp -> {
        pp.setJMSReplyTo(activeMQQueue);
        return pp;
    });
}
```

**Via ActiveMQ Artemis console:**

This is where the inconstancy comes as the `Object` received is an `ActiveMQDestination` which makes setting the `CamelJmsDestination` much more involved.

Am I wasting my time here? Should I just grab the queue name and construct the uri manually? Or I am missing some logic as to how this works? Or maybe I'm not using the Artemis console in the correct way?

```
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.setHeader("CamelJmsDestination", header("JMSReplyTo"))
```

[image: ActiveMQ Artemis Console. Send message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `javax.jms.Message#setJMSReplyTo(Destination)` you have to pass a [`javax.jms.Destination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Destination.html) which must implement one of the following:

- `javax.jms.Queue`
- `javax.jms.TemporaryQueue`
- `javax.jms.Topic`
- `javax.jms.TemporaryTopic`

In order to reproduce this semantic via text in the web console of ActiveMQ Artemis you need to prefix your destination's name with one of the following respectively:

- `queue://`
- `temp-queue://`
- `topic://`
- `temp-topic://`

So when you set the `JMSReplyTo` header try using `queue://RESPONSE_QUEUE`.

When your application then receives this message and invokes `getJMSReplyTo()` it will receive a `javax.jms.Queue` implementation (i.e. `ActiveMQQueue`) and then you can use `getQueueName()` to get the `String` name of the queue if necessary.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I though I had already replied. 
This is exactly what I was looking for! I have tested and can now see the queue is set to true in the destination. I think I assumed that it would set the queue by default as it was coming from a queue in the first place.